# Derive expressions for the formal power series $\cos(kz)$ and $\sin(kz)$, where $k$ is an arbitrary integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I'm working on some past exam questions, and I am struggling with the second part of this question:

Define the formal power series by the formulas:

$$\sin(z) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}z^{2n-1}, \space \cos(z) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n} $$

> (a) Show $\exp(iz) = \cos(z) + i\sin(z)$
>
> (b) Use this relation to derive expressions for the formal power
>   series $\sin(kz)$ and $\cos(kz)$ in terms of $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$  ,
>   both of which may occur in each expression and $k$ is a positive
>   integer.

I think I have done the first part correctly (although I am not sure if it is stringent enough) but I am struggling with part (b), and would greatly appreciate some help.

Here is what I have so far:

Given the formulas for $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$, I simply write out a few terms for both:

$$ \cos(z) = 1 - \frac{z^2}{2!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} - ...$$ and $$ i\sin(z) = iz - \frac{iz^3}{3!} + \frac{iz^5}{5!} - ...$$ Then adding these together, I get:

$$ \cos(z) + i\sin(z) = 1 + iz - \frac{z^2}{2!} - \frac{iz^3}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{4!} + \frac{iz^5}{5!} - ...$$ which can be re-written as:

$$ \cos(z) + i\sin(z) = 1 + iz + \frac{(iz)^2}{2!} + \frac{(iz)^3}{3!} + \frac{(iz)^4}{4!} + \frac{(iz)^5}{5!} + ...= \exp(iz)$$ Is this a valid way to show (a)?

**EDIT:**

For part(b), I have made some progress, thanks to the help below. But I don't think my answer is complete.

From (a), I have  $$\exp(iz) = \cos(z) + i\sin(z) \implies \exp(ikz) = \exp(iz)^k = \cos(kz) + i\sin(kz) = (\cos(z) + i\sin(z))^k $$

Using the binomial theorem:

$$ \cos(kz) + i\sin(kz) = (\cos(z))^k + {k\choose1}(\cos(z))^{k-1}i\sin(z) + {k\choose2}(\cos(z))^{k-2}(i\sin(z))^2 +...+{k\choose{k-1}}(\cos(z))(i\sin(z))^{k-1} + (i\sin(z))^{k}$$

Collecting the coefficients gives me:

$$\cos(kz) = (\cos(z))^k - {k\choose2}(\cos(z))^{k-2}(\sin(z))^2 + {k\choose4}(\cos(z))^{k-4}(\sin(z))^4 -...$$ and

$$ \sin(kz) = {k\choose1}(\cos(z))^{k-1}(\sin(z)) - {k\choose3}(\cos(z))^{k-3}(\sin(z))^3 + {k\choose5}(\cos(z))^{k-5}(\sin(z))^5 - ... $$

Writing these in summation notation I get:

$$\cos(kz) = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n {k\choose{2n}}(\cos(z))^{k-(2n)}(\sin(z))^{2n} $$ and

$$\sin(kz) = \sum_{n=0} (-1)^n {k\choose{2n+1}}(\cos(z))^{k-(2n+1)}(\sin(z))^{2n+1} $$

However, I am not sure what my upper limit summation should be? From testing a few numbers for $k$, it seems to $\lfloor{\frac{k}{2}}\rfloor$ But I'm not sure if this is correct, as I have never really seen this before.

Also, since it is supposed to be an expression for a formal power series (does that mean the limit of summation should be $\infty$? But then that doesn't really make sense with my expression?

Help!

Comment: (a) seems correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to note that we have the following:
$$
\cos(kz) + i\sin(kz) = e^{ikz} = (e^{iz})^k = (\cos(z) + i\sin(z))^k
$$
If you then look at the real and imaginary parts of this expression, you should be able to figure something out.

As for the fact that $e^{ikz} = (e^{iz})^k$:

Let us sketch a proof more generally that $e^{a+b}= e^ae^b$. Since it would then follow, e.g., that $e^{iz}e^{iz} = e^{iz + iz}$ as desired (for $k = 2$)

In this case:

$$
e^{a+b} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(a+b)^k}{k!} \\
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{m=0}^k{k \choose m}a^{k-m}b^m \\
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{m=0}^k\frac{k!}{(k-m)!m!}a^{k-m}b^m \\
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^k\frac{1}{(k-m)!m!}a^{k-m}b^m
$$

Now, take a look at the definition of the product of two power series, say $e^a$ and $e^b$. Using that, and a little bit of induction, the claim should follow.

Comment: thanks Simon, but I'm still stuck. From your hint, all I could think of to do is move the $i sin(kz)$ from the LHS to the RHS and then use the binomial theorem to expand out the $(cos(z)+isin(z))^k$, but I'm not sure whether that is valid. I didn't arrive at anything obvious. Also, I just wanted to be sure, your expression for $e^{ikz}$ is referring to the formal power series right? Because although I know that they essentially behave the same way, I'm not sure if we can freely interchange the properties of $e^x$ and $exp(z)$?

Comment: Ah, that's fair. You should probably either a) prove that the formal power series $e^x$ has the same properties as the function $\exp(x)$ (which isn't too hard, and is a good exercise), or b) verify with your instructor that it's OK to assume that.

Comment: As for your description with the binomial theorem, it sounds like you're doing it just fine. E.g. $(\cos(x) + i \sin(x))^2 = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x) + 2i\sin(x)\cos(x)$, and hence e.g. $\cos(2x) = \cos^2(x) - \sin^2(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll verify. But I'm still not sure if what I have is correct. E.g. I have $$cos(kz) = cos(z)^k + {k\choose1}cos(z)^{k-1}isin(z)+{k\choose2}cos(z)^{k-2}isin(z)^2+...+{k\choose{k-1}}cos(z)isin(z)^{k-1}+isin(z)^k-isin(kz)$$, but I still have $isin(kz)$ in the expression?

Comment: Two things: Make sure that you bracket correctly. When you write, say, $\cos(z)^{k-2}i\sin(z)^2$, this should be $\cos(z)^{k-2}\big(i\sin(z)\big)^2$. Secondly, $\cos(kz)$ is only the real part of this! So that should help.

Comment: Noted regarding the brackets - but sorry, I'm still confused! For example if $k=3$, then I would have: $$cos(3z) = (cos(z))^3+{3\choose1}(cos(z))^2(isin(z))+{3\choose2}(cos(z))(isin(z))^2+(isin(z))^3-isin(3z)$$ Aren't these terms: $isin(z), (isin(z))^3-isin(3z)$ imaginary? I'm supposed to derive an expression for $cos(kz)$ in terms of $cos(z)$ and $sin(z)$, so would $isin(z)$ be ok? I suppose the question doesn't specifically say...Is my interpretation incorrect? Thanks again.

Comment: If you write it as $$\cos(3z) +i \sin(z)= (\cos(z))^3 - {3 \choose 2} \cos(z)(\sin(z))^2 + i\Big({3\choose 1}(\cos(z))^2\sin(z) - (\sin(z))^3\Big)$$ then identifying the real part of the LHS ($\cos(3z)$) with that of the RHS, which is $$(\cos(z))^3 + 3\cos(z)(\sin(z))^2$$ gives the answer to half of it. Equating the imaginary parts says then that $\sin(3z) =$...

Comment: Don't forget that $i^2 = -1$ and so $i^3 = -i$, $i^4 = 1$, ...

Comment: got you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wrote my answer in summation notation (above), and it seems to work, from plugging in a few values for $k$. The upper limit of the summation appears to be $\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor$. But should a formal power series have $\infty$ as the upper limit?

Comment: A formal power series may have an infinite upper limit; and in a sense, this one does, but it is hidden. In your case, the upper limit of the summation in question should be $\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \rfloor$ as you said, or it could be infinite (since ${m \choose n} = 0$ usually for $n > m$). However, that doesn't change the fact that your series still has an infinite upper limit in terms of the variable $z$!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I actually realised that a little later, once $n>k$, ${k \choose n}$ is just $0$, which cancels out everything afterwards. So I can just keep it as $\infty$.

Comment: I follow your proof as well. Would this be correct for an induction proof? As the base case let $n=2$, then we have shown that $$\exp(2iz) = \exp(iz+iz) = \exp(iz)\exp(iz)=(exp(iz))^2$$ The induction hypothesis is then $n=k$  $$\exp(kiz) = \exp(iz+iz+....+iz) = \exp(iz)\exp(iz)...\exp(iz) =(exp(iz))^k$$ Where there are $k$ terms in between. Then $n=k+1$ is essentially exactly the same thing but with $k+1$ terms in between, which I'm not sure is really valid, because I feel like I am just restating the hypothesis?

Comment: The induction step would really be to note that $$e^{(k+1)iz} = e^{kiz + iz} = e^{kiz}e^{iz}$$ and then by induction, we would have that $$e^{kiz} = (e^{iz})^k$$ and hence $$e^{(k+1)iz} = e^{kiz}e^{iz} = (e^{iz})^k e^{iz} = (e^{iz})^{k+1}$$

Comment: Ahh right. Thanks so much. Really have a good understanding now!